# PostgreSQL COPY csv including Quotes

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, copy

This is a very simple problem, I am using the psql terminal command COPY as shown bellow

```
COPY tbname FROM '/tmp/file.csv'
delimiter '|' csv;
```

However this file.csv contains data such as

```
random|stuff|32"
```

as well as

```
random|other "stuff"|15
```

I tried to use the double quote to escape the quotes as the Postgres site suggested

```
random|stuff|32""
random|other ""stuff""|15
```

This seems to remove the quotes completely which I don't want.
Is there a way to get the import to just treat these quotes as regular characters so that they appear in the database as they do in the csv file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html), the default quote symbol is ", so you need to provide a QUOTE argument with a different symbol. The quote symbol has to be a single one-byte character.

```
COPY tbname FROM '/tmp/file.csv'
delimiter '|' QUOTE '}' csv; -- use a symbol you know does not appear in your file.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks, I wasn't expecting such a nice solution

Comment: would be great to see a solution for the case where you can't be sure of any symbol's absence.

Comment: @mlinth I have a situation where i'm using COPY command to copy table data into a csv file. In the CSV file I'm getting all string values wrapped around with double-quotes. Will adding similar QUOTE '}' help in removing those double-quotes?

Comment: @Mano I think the default quote mark is a double quote, so I *think* to remove then you would need QUOTE '' i.e. no quote mark. Haven't tried it though.