# POSTGRESQL invalid input syntax for type integer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, types, import

I am a novice user of PostgresQL. I found out in Internet interesting DB, which consists of 3 tables. Every of this table is in CSV format. However I could smoothly copy the first one to my sql database. Right now I have the following problem:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "43950100,43950010,TUR,GUNES Senol (TUR),S,1,"RUSTU ",GK,"
> CONTEXT:  COPY worldcupsplayers, line 25645, column roundid: "43950100,43950010,TUR,GUNES Senol (TUR),S,1,"RUSTU ",GK,"

Every row in a table has the same structure, as follows:
`43950100,43950010,TUR,GUNES Senol (TUR),S,1,"RUSTU ",GK,`
I am wondering why in such row I have a problem (line 25645), while it looks as other ones.
I am trying to copy it with this command:

```
COPY worldcupsplayers(RoundID, MatchID, team_initials, coach_name, line_up, shirt_number, player_name, position, event)
FROM 'C:\Users\Public\worldcup\worldcupplayers.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

[table structure]

[image: 1]

UPDATE: rows above and below

```
25643 - 43950100,43950008,SVN,KATANEC Srecko (SVN),N,23,BULAJIC,, 
25644 - 43950100,43950010,BRA,SCOLARI Luiz Felipe (BRA),S,1,MARCOS,GK, 
25645 - 43950100,43950010,TUR,GUNES Senol (TUR),S,1,"RUSTU ",GK, 
25646 - 43950100,43950010,BRA,SCOLARI Luiz Felipe (BRA),S,2,CAFU,C,
```

As u may see they are all the same, with the commas every row has the same structure.

Comment: Your row doesn't seem to match up to the listed columns. Your example has 8 but your command is saying you have 9. So it's probably wrapping to the next row and eventually you have a type mismatch.

Comment: Doesn't the coma, at the and of the line, insists that there is another (empty) column?

Comment: The quotes are suspicious, look at the faulty line and the one before and validate the quotes.

Comment: I made an update with rows below and above

Comment: I agree with @JGH.  The quotes are likely giving you grief.  Check out this StackOverflow:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629475/postgresql-copy-csv-including-quotes  and PostgresSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-copy.html.    The solution will depend on whether you want the quotes to be part of the imported data or not.

Comment: Guys, you had right, I replaced every quote with a blank space and now i could import it. Thank you very much for your attention :)